# quitting browser call with a twist

Tags: debugging, r, browser

Imagine you're debugging a function within a function. You would be on level 2 (`Browser [2]`). Is there a way to quit level 2 and go to level 1? `Q` will drop you out of any debugging, so I'm looking for something that would just quit the current level.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you get the Browser[2] prompt? For all my efforts of nesting functions within functions all I can get is a Browser[1] prompt... I'm sure I've seen it...

Comment: I use Rterm. What do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change to the level 2 function body, then get it to throw an error.  Then set the error option to `recover`.  Now you can move between functions as you please.

```
foo <- function() bar()
bar <- function() stop("start debug here")

options(error = recover)
foo()
```

Comment: Another way would be to have `browser();stop()` until you are absolutely sure you want to run your function. You remove `stop()` and be on your way. Don't forget to `source()` the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Is `c` what you are looking for? It will continue execution of the current level and return you to level 1. Presumably you want whatever was running at level 2 to finish so level 1 is in a consistent state?

Comment: Another way of doing what I want, but let's say I want to quit before (imagine that the run lasts hours, as is my case).